# PHP SQL data parse from DB table give out error as `Trying to get property of non-object`

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in db, as 'bookings' i m trying to print specific columns of it according to selected email in the table rows.

But when i pass the email through the id link, it gives out a error of `Trying to get property of non-object`

My html link as follows:

```
<td><a href='some.php?id=<?php echo $row2['email'];?>'>Know more</a></td>
```

then the some.php pages as goes:

```
<?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email =" .$_GET["id"];
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {                               
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {                                   
?>
    <tr >
        <td><?php echo ($row2["user"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($row2["location"]); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo ($row2["bookedat"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($row2["stay"]); ?></td>
    </tr> 
<?php     }
    } else {
echo "0 results";
            }
?>
```

Now the email is being passed correctly. i have checked that. but when it comes to the php page. it gives out the error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\some.php on line 186` in here the line 186 is `if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {`

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: `var_dump($result2)` check what it gives you

Comment: check `$conn->error` , your query must be having some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with query:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email " .$_GET["id"];
```

Asume change

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email ='" .$_GET["id"]."'";
```

or better use parametrized query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email = ?" ;
```

and set parameter $_GET["id"] after, and double check if $_GET["id"] had some value.

Comment: `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email = " .$_GET["id"];` didn't worked

Comment: or maybe missing quotes?

Comment: Please do let me know>>

Comment: $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE email ='" .$_GET["id"]."'";

Comment: but strongly recommend to use prepeared mysql queries (more at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent SQL injection from PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

if ($result2 = $conn->query($sql2)) {

```
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 // do stuff per row

}

/* free result set */
$result->free();
```

}

The error refers to:
Array / object notation.

To access the elements in an array, use array notation: $product['prodname']

$product->prodname is object notation, which can only be used to access object attributes and methods.

Check The object is not empty or missing the property is missing. To check vardump the object ... eg. var_dump($object);die(); if your in development, don't die on a production server :L)

Comment: but i don't have any arrray i my db table?